# How to solve this problem without using a strucure? (Getting Time Limit Exceeded)

Tags: python, arrays, queue

Recently I took part in a competition for middle school girls. I ran across this problem and I have been working on it for a few weeks. Here is the problem:

I. Ventilator Shipments

At the local hospital, Gabriela keeps track of all the ventilator shipments. Recently, a new factory has been established to produce ventilators. She knows that the new factory is almost extraordinary in its production, as on a certain day Di, it produces the same amount of ventilators as the product of the previous K days' production. However, the hospital's computer can only handle non-negative numbers less than P, a prime number. Gabriela knows the production value, Di, for each of the first K days. Accordingly, Gabriela wants to know how many ventilators are produced after N days. If this number is greater than or equal to P, the computer displays the remainder of the number of ventilators produced divided by P.

Input

```
Line 1: Three space-separated integers N, K, P
Lines 2...K+1: A single integer Di
```

Output

```
Line 1: Number of ventilators produced after N days as displayed by the computer
```

Example Input:

```
5 2 7
1
3
```

Output:

```
6
```

Note:

```
2 ≤ N ≤ 1000000
1 ≤ K ≤ N
2 ≤ P ≤ 1000003 (where P is guaranteed to be prime)
1 ≤ Di ≤ P−1
```

The time limit for this problem has been extended to 2000 ms.

I have tried 3 different methods

Here is the first:

```
import math

import sys
string=sys.stdin.readline()
string=string.rstrip()
arr=[0]*3
arr=string.split(' ')
n=int(arr[0])
k=int(arr[1])
p=int(arr[2])


mylist=[0]*k
for i in range (k):
  a=int(sys.stdin.readline())
  mylist[i]=a%p

product=math.prod(mylist)
for start in range (n-k):
  smallest=mylist[start%k]
  mylist[start%k]=(product%p)
  product=product*(product%p)
  product=product//smallest
sys.stdout.write (str(mylist[start%k]))
```

In another method I used a queue:

```
import math
from collections import deque
import sys
string=sys.stdin.readline()
string=string.rstrip()
arr=[0]*3
arr=string.split(' ')
n=int(arr[0])
k=int(arr[1])
p=int(arr[2])
q=deque()

for i in range (k):
  a=int(sys.stdin.readline())
  q.append(a%p)

product=math.prod(q)

for i in range (n-k):
  q.append(product%p)
  product=product*(product%p)
  smallest=q.popleft()
  product=product//smallest

sys.stdout.write (str(q.pop())+'\n')
```

However, I'm still getting time limit exceeded on test cast 8. Given the time and space constraints, I don't think I can any kind of structure (list, queue, etc.) to solve this problem. Can someone give me an idea on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your data structures so much as your algorithmic overhead.  Your first attempt includes a multiplication and five divisions in each loop, plus two list accesses and four assignments.  Your second attempt has three divisions, three assignments, and two list-changing operations.

You might want to experiment a little to determine roughly how many operations you can perform in 2 seconds.  How long does it take you to run 10*6 loop iterations with a trivial body?  I suspect that you're not going be able to carry out an iterative solution.

Instead of carrying out each iterative computation individually, try focusing on the problem as given.  You do *not* need each day's output; you need only to compute the *final* day's output, modulo `p`.  That production is a high-order product of the input production sequence (the "seed" days of production).  How many times does each of those days appear in that final product?  For large `n`, what is the cycle of values produced?  Most importantly, what factor gives you a modular residue of 1?  (It's `p-1` for any factor)

Compute how many times each factor appears in the final product; call it `use`.  Reduce that mod `p-1`.  Now you have an expression such as

```
product = k[0] ** (use[0] % (p-1) ) *
          k[1] ** (use[1] % (p-1) ) *
          ...

print(product % p)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. I was wondering what use would be in the sample input

Comment: The 5th day's production is 1^5 * 3^3, so `use = [5, 3]`.

Comment: Okay, but how did you find use?

Comment: As I said, I computed how many times each factor would appear in the final result.  This is algebra -- do the computations by hand, work out the series, and examine how the exponents advance.